# lawn irrigation valve box filling up with water

Tags: leak, valve, irrigation

I noticed an irrigation control box filling up with water even when the sprinklers and gate valve were off. In order to trace the leak I removed approx 4 inches of dirt to reveal the fittings. I noticed water trickling out from under this round area - I think its called the bonnet? Its the part that is screwed onto the T pipe joint. I tried tightening it which only slowed the leak. This joint has probably been buried under damp soil for years - in fact it moves easily when I attempt to open or close the valve.

Is it possible to get a new valve and replace it to stop the leak? Could it be a rubber washer? I've got a wrench, channel locks, plumbers tape. Here are photos that may help.

[image]

Comment: "I've got a wrench, channel locks, plumbers tape." A) Good on you for having some basic tools. B) Even better on you for telling us that! If only others would do so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rebuild the valve much easier than replacing and rebuilding is less expensive. I have seen oring and fiber/ gasket material under the “bonnet” a set of washers and some valve stem packing in kits and all are good things to have to rebuild valves like this, my original kit was a metal box it is so old and I have refilled it dozens of times spending very little but saving 10-100x the cost of the parts compared to having it done. The last all around valve rebuild kit I saw at a plumbing & electric specialty store was 20$ it had everything needed for at least 10 rebuilds and if just seats more than 20. I suggest all home owners should have a kit and my kids got them as house warming presents but I still end up doing the rebuilds often.

Comment: I buy my kids smoke detectors.  Both honorable, though mildly passive aggressive gifts.  I'm sure they would prefer sofas.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll give it a shot this weekend - are replacement or repair kits easily available at stores like HD? And just to be certain, this fix is possible without removing the T joint - just the bit above the bonnet, right?

Comment: @eszed yes, you _should_ be able to find them at a big-box store. If not, _any_ plumbing supply place will have it. There's a chance it'll even be cheaper at the plumbing supply place!

Comment: HD didn't have it. Said this was an old style valve. I don't think I'm skilled or courageous enough to replace the entire valve (T joint portion) as there isn't much room to work. I'll try a dedicated plumbing supply store to see if they just have the top portion of the valve. Otherwise I'll try my luck with a compatible washer and teflon tape.

Comment: Update: I went to a speciality or dedicated plumbing store for the first time ever and found it. I was blown away by their inventory. It was pricey (CAD $45) but I found the whole valve joint and took it apart to swap. Now I'm waiting for the kids to step to sleep or step out so I can shut off the water and begin. It didn't have a washer under it, just metal threads.

Comment: Well things have increased over the years , sorry I was so far off but repair is normally much easier and less expensive than a replacement. I have remodeled several dozen Victorians and 30-50’s homes this is where a plumbing and electric specialty store is the king , Home desperate can help for 70’s + fixtures sometime but running around cost time and fuel and as you found the specialty store had the part.

Comment: Not to worry Ed. Update 2: changing that part didn't help. Water still gushed out. I then applied perhaps half roll of teflon tape which didn't help either. I can't possibly tighten it any more without stripping the threads. Plus angles are terrible to develop any torque. I'm out of ideas and may call a plumber.

Comment: Update 3: fixed! What I did wrong the first time was try to thread the new bonnet/stem to the joint with the gate closed which meant fewer turns and thereby no seal. While waiting in queue at the store I was fiddling around with the old parts and realized this by chance. I went home immediately and thread the bonnet with the gate fully open this time and lo and behold I got at least 4*360 turns. This stopped the leak. Time to cancel the plumbers appointment.

Comment: Awesome you made it past apprentice DIY plumber + I was wondering if the valve body was damaged but you figured it out, now you have done more plumbing than about 1/2 the home owners. Thanks for letting us know and this helps us to remember to remind others the shaft needs to be retracted (I remember this on valve stem packing when it has to be opened because I have had the same issue)

Answer (score 0):

usually it's a fibre washer in that location (not rubber) but it looks like previously someone tried to use teflon tape there.

It looks like it's been wet there for a while. you may need to replace the whole stem assembly.

Comment: HD said this is an old style valve and they don't carry it. I'm having trouble identifying and naming this style of gate valve. Would any stem replacement kit work? I don't think it's the stem - it leaks even when the valve is off. The bonnet area is loose and isn't gripping the T joint well which leads me to believe it isn't the stem inside.